# Excel VBA, pop-up window to define range to perform multiple criteria sorting

Tags: excel, vba, sorting

amateur macro writer here. I am looking for some guidance in how to write a macro which does the following:

Pop-up box which prompts user to define a range of data e.g. A26:K35.

Use this range to then perform a custom filtering e.g. Sort on Column A, then B, then C in ascending order.

The following code, I pieced together, will provide the prompt, and sort based on A - I cannot seem to add the additional criteria.

Any guidance would be greatly appreciated.

```
Sub Sort_and_Subtotal_CheckBox()

Dim SortRng As Range

Set SortRng = Application.InputBox("Select the range to sort", "Select Range", 0, , , , , 8)

SortRng.Select
Selection.Sort Key1:=SortRng, Order1:=xlAscending, Header:=xlGuess, _
OrderCustom:=1, MatchCase:=False, Orientation:=xlTopToBottom, _
DataOption1:=xlSortNormal
Range("A1").Select


End Sub
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You may try something like this. Look at the comments I added in the code.

```
Sub Sort_and_Subtotal_CheckBox()

Dim SortRng As Range

On Error Resume Next
Set SortRng = Application.InputBox("Select the range to sort", "Select Range", Type:=8)
On Error GoTo 0

If Not SortRng Is Nothing Then
    'SortRng.Cells(1, 1) --> First cell in column 1 in the selected range
    'SortRng.Cells(1, 2) --> First cell in column 2 in the selected range
    'SortRng.Cells(1, 3) --> First cell in column 3 in the selected range
    SortRng.Sort key1:=SortRng.Cells(1, 1), order1:=xlAscending, key2:=SortRng.Cells(1, 2), order2:=xlAscending, key3:=SortRng.Cells(1, 3), order3:=xlAscending, Header:=xlGuess
End If
End Sub
```

Comment: Thank you for the (very fast) reply sktneer. Works perfectly - much appreciated!

Comment: You're welcome! Glad it worked as desired. Please take a minute to accept the answer to mark your question as Solved. :)